# Naturally sort a list moving alphanumeric values to the end

Tags: python, sorting, natural-sort

I have a list of strings I want to natural sort:

```
c = ['0', '1', '10', '11', '2', '2Y', '3', '3Y', '4', '4Y', '5', '5Y', '6', '7', '8', '9', '9Y']
```

In addition to natural sort, I want to move all entries that are not pure number strings to the end. My expected output is this:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '2Y', '3Y', '4Y', '5Y', '9Y']
```

Do note that everything has to be natsorted - even the alphanumeric strings.

I know I can use the `natsort` package to get what I want, but that alone does not do it for me. I need to do this with *two* sort calls - one to natural sort, and another to move non-pure numeric strings to the end.

```
import natsort as ns
r = sorted(ns.natsorted(c), key=lambda x: not x.isdigit())

print(r)
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '2Y', '3Y', '4Y', '5Y', '9Y']
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to use `natsort` in a crafty manner and reduce this to a single sort call.

Comment: Why worry about performing a 2nd sort? TimSort is optimised for sorting sequences that contain sorted subsequences, so the 2nd sort will be very fast. And you can improve the performance by eliminating that lambda: `key=str.isdigit, reverse=True`

Comment: @PM2Ring If you could elaborate a bit and turn that into an answer, I'd appreciate that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually perform this using `natsorted` and the correct choice of `key`.

```
>>> ns.natsorted(d, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), x))
['0',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '10',
 '11',
 '2Y',
 '3Y',
 '4Y',
 '5Y',
 '9Y']
```

The key returns a tuple with the original input as the second element. Strings that are digits get placed at the front, all others at the back, then the subsets are sorted individually.

As a side note, [Willem Van Onsem's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47240297/1399279) uses `natsort_key`, which has been deprecated as of `natsort` version 3.0.4 (if you turn on `DeprecationWarning` in your interpreter you will see that, and the function is now undocumented). It's actually pretty inefficient... it is preferred to use `natort_keygen` which returns a natural sorting key.  `natsort_key` calls this under the hood, so for every input you are creating a new function and then calling it once.

Below I repeat the tests shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47240450/1399279), and I added my solution using the `natsorted` method as well as the timing of the other solutions using `natsort_keygen` instead of `natsort_key`.

```
In [13]: %timeit sorted(d, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), ns.natsort_key(x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 33.3 s per loop

In [14]: natsort_key = ns.natsort_keygen()

In [15]: %timeit sorted(d, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), natsort_key(x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 11.2 s per loop

In [16]: %timeit sorted(ns.natsorted(d), key=str.isdigit, reverse=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 9.77 s per loop

In [17]: %timeit ns.natsorted(d, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), x))
1 loop, best of 3: 23.8 s per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

`natsort` has a function **`natsort_key`** that converts the item into a tuple based on which sorting is done.

So you can use it as:

```
sorted(c, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), *ns.natsort_key(x)))
```

This produces:

```
>>> sorted(c, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), *ns.natsort_key(x)))
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '2Y', '3Y', '4Y', '5Y', '9Y']
```

You can also use it without iterable unpacking, since in that case we have two 2-tuples, and in case of a tie-break on the first item, it will thus compare the outcome of the `natsort_key` call:

```
sorted(c, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), ns.natsort_key(x)))
```

Comment: Hmm, is this a 3.6 only function?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: no. I manage to let this work in Python-3.5.3. Natsort is 5.1.0.

Comment: My bad, the iterable unpacking is python3.5+ (I'm on 4). That's not an issue.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: wel actually I don't think the unpacking is necessary, since recursively, it will aim to sort the elements.

Comment: True, but it's probably slightly faster if you do flatten the tuple in the key function.

Comment: `ns.natsort_key` is deprecated and rather inefficient (it was removed from documentation and only kept for backwards-compatibility). Please view it as an implementation detail at this point. The preferred method is `natsort_key = ns.natsort_keygen()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47244729/1399279 for just how much faster it is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm grateful to Willem Van Onsem for posting his answer. However, I should note here that the original function's performance is an order of magnitude faster. Taking PM2 Ring's suggestions into account, here's some benchmarks between the two methods:

**Setup**

```
c = \
['0',
 '1',
 '10',
 '11',
 '2',
 '2Y',
 '3',
 '3Y',
 '4',
 '4Y',
 '5',
 '5Y',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 '9Y']
d = c * (1000000 // len(c) + 1)  # approximately 1M elements
```

[**Willem's solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47240297/4909087)

```
%timeit sorted(d, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), ns.natsort_key(x)))
1 loop, best of 3: 2.78 s per loop
```

[**Original** *(w/ PM 2Ring's enhancement)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240184/naturally-sort-a-list-moving-alphanumeric-values-to-the-end/47240297#comment81430834_47240184)

```
%timeit sorted(ns.natsorted(d), key=str.isdigit, reverse=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 796 ms per loop
```

The explanation for the high performance of the original is because Tim Sort seems to be highly optimised for nearly sorted lists.

---

**Sanity Check**

```
x = sorted(d, key=lambda x: (not x.isdigit(), ns.natsort_key(x)))
y = sorted(ns.natsorted(d), key=str.isdigit, reverse=True)

all(i == j for i, j in zip(x, y))
True
```